# Styling broken for close votes on mobile

Tags: bug, user-interface

Simple issue. When casting a close vote, you're told which other votes have been cast.

#### On the PC, it looks like this:

[image: Casting a close vote on the PC]

#### On a mobile, however, that red background behind the number is missing:

[image: Casting a close vote on a mobile]

That's all.

The mobile screenshot was taken on an Android using Dolphin Browser, a few hours ago. It's been like that for a while.